# python threading: how to kill the child thread while maintaining the master thread?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading

I use the threading module in python.
the master process is listening the port all the time. Once message comes, start a child thread. But if error happens in this child thread, how to kill it while maintaining the master thread? So that the master one can still listening on port until some new message comes. How to achieve this in threading?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: thread.exit() ?

Comment: If we are talking about a subprocess, this isn't really threading.  Python offers both multithreading and multiprocessing as ways of writing concurrent processes.

Comment: sorry for unclear words. i think i m talking about thread. still need help, i have revised my questions. Thx

Comment: To remind everyone, killing threads by another thread is a very bad idea.